# Why does compiling zlib with MSVC compilers work fine and yet gives a syntax error with Cygwin?

Tags: c++, cmake, zlib

I'm trying to compile [zlib](https://github.com/madler/zlib.git) on cygwin and I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/windres: /cygdrive/d/zlib-1.2.11/win32/zlib1.rc:7: syntax error
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/build.make:258: CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/win32/zlib1.obj] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:109: CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:116: CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:188: zlib] Error 2
```

Note, the library compiles using visual studio compilers and the static version of the library also compiles fine with cygwin. Looking at the syntax error, we have a macro:

```
#ifdef GCC_WINDRES
VS_VERSION_INFO     VERSIONINFO
#else
VS_VERSION_INFO     VERSIONINFO MOVEABLE IMPURE LOADONCALL DISCARDABLE <----this line causes the syntax error
#endif
  FILEVERSION       ZLIB_VER_MAJOR,ZLIB_VER_MINOR,ZLIB_VER_REVISION,0
  PRODUCTVERSION    ZLIB_VER_MAJOR,ZLIB_VER_MINOR,ZLIB_VER_REVISION,0
  FILEFLAGSMASK     VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
#ifdef _DEBUG
  FILEFLAGS     1
#else
  FILEFLAGS     0
#endif
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for getting this library to compile?

Comment: try tom remove `MOVEABLE IMPURE LOADONCALL DISCARDABLE`